# ActiveRecord touch causing deadlocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My app uses `touch` extensively in order to take advantage of Rails' template caching system. There's a certain type of work my app does when many relationships are created between many different objects in a batch. Sometimes, some of this work results in the resulting cascading `touch`es causing deadlock.

I can code around this for the one scenario where I am seeing it happen often, but seeing it has brought to light the larger problem, which could happen in other scenarios, albeit it's very unlikely.

To understand this, think about two people following one another on Twitter at exactly the same moment. They both click "Follow", resulting in the relationship objects being created between them and then each of their records being `touch`ed. If these touches become interweaved:

1. process 1 touches user A
2. process 2 touches user B
3. process 1 touches user B
4. process 2 touches user A

Each process is using a database transaction, so this will result in deadlock.

Am I wrong that this could happen in normal app operation outside of my weird batch job scenario? If I'm not wrong, is there any solution? Can I somehow move the `touch`es to be outside of the transactions? (Last Write Wins is fine for updating updated_at anyway...)

**update - more explanation of data models**

```
class Follow
  belongs_to :follower, touch: true
  belongs_to :followee, touch: true
end

@u1 = User.find(1)
@u2 = User.find(2)

# Background Job 1
Follow.create!(follower: @u1, followee: @u2)

# Background Job 2
Follow.create!(follower: @u2, followee: @u1)
```

Comment: Do you have like a bidirectional touch? cause I can't imagine why touching a model will trigger a second model, and touching the second model will also touch the first model, could you clarify the models structure and relations.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady okay see my update above

Comment: I don't understand how the dead lock happens, even if both touch at the same time, you'll just touch the same record twice, could you explain this dead lock behavior? do you mean both jobs just hang waiting for each other?

Comment: Yes, both jobs hanging waiting for each other, because they are locking the rows for update inside their own transactions.

Comment: did you try the answer I added, it tries to lock both records together at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what makes that deadlock but you could add a pessimistic lock on both records while you're handling them, this will prevent another request from handling them until the lock is released, `ActiveRecord` will wait for the lock release before proceeding.

```
User.transaction do
  @u1, @u2 = User.lock.where(id: [1,2])
  # Those two records are now locked, other transaction instances
  # can't proceed till this transaction block is exited 
  Follow.create!(follower: @u1, followee: @u2)
end
# lock is released here
```

**Note:** passing `id: [2,1]` won't return them in that order, so you'll need to handle that condition.

**Note 2:** Too much locking might affect your overall app performance, since the user model is probably a heavily used model, but I guess it all depends on how often these follows happen.

---

**Update:** Here's a second way that also might work, first the follow model, no touches, but instead an `after_create`

```
class Follow
  belongs_to :follower
  belongs_to :followee

  after_create :touch_users

  def touch_users
    # no locking and direct database update
    User.where(id: [follower.id, followee.id]).update_all(updated_at: :Time.now)
  end
end
```

Then the controller would do a normal transaction, or not at all, cause you don't need it

```
Follow.create!(follower: @u1, followee: @u2)
```

**NOTE:** `#update_all` doesn't fire the activerecord call backs and the queries are done directly on the database, if you have any `after_update` methods then you might want to avoid this method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer -- I'm aware that I can lock to work around the problem, but I guess I am more interested in a general solution that moves touches outside of the transaction entirely. Maybe I am asking for the impossible :)

Comment: you might move the touch from the association to an after create action, and fire both at the same time, this way the slightly older transaction will raise a stale object error, this is the optimistic locking, or you could just do the locking in the after action and that would be a lot better, cause its locks for a shorter time, ill update my answer

Comment: now that i think of it, why would they block the user, do you have any locks in your background code? could you add that block to the question?